# Can't get osm2po to work

Tags: osm2po

I have downloaded `osm2po 4.7.7` but when trying to follow the instrutions in either the documentation but I'm not able to access the map in my browser on `http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService`. What I have done is:

- to download and extract `osm2po 4.7.7` and the map `denmark-latest.osm.pbf`.
- to run (in cmd.exe) `java -jar osm2po-core-4.7.7-signed.jar prefix=dk "C:\users\mgn.mes\documents\denmark-latest.osm.pbf"` from the directory where i unpacked `osm2po 4.7.7`.

Then osm2po starts ad I'm prompted for accepting terms by hitting enter. I hit enter and the program ends. Then I try to enter `http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService` in the browser, but nothing i returned.

Do I need to change the `.config` file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressed Enter? ... Enter "yes" and then press Return.